# positive or negative denotation question. Please help!

Tags: grammar, word-choice, speech

Denotation refers to a word's meaning. Does the word MOBILE have a positive or negative denotation?

Comment: The *denotation* is the dictionary entry for the word. Do you mean *connotation*?

Answer (score 3):

**Denotations** are neutral. They're simply the literal dictionary definition of a word, and mobile's definition is [able to move or be moved freely or easily](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/able-to-move-and-ability-to-be-moved), or relating to portable technology.

The term you may be looking for is **connotation**, which is the positive or negative meaning *associated* with a phrase.

Consider this: If I invite you to my cottage in the forest, it's probably going to be a good time and we might see a fairy or some fawns, but if I invite you to my cabin in the woods, someone's getting murdered.  They both mean the same thing (house in the middle of a large group of trees) but have different inferred meanings, or **connotations**.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mean "connotation." "Mobile" is just descriptive -- it doesn't have a feel of being bad or good.

"Mobile home" is cheaper than an ordinary home, so that's a little more negative. "Upwardly mobile" is positive. "Mobile phone" is probably a little positive, since it's a luxury and when people refer to this device negatively it's usually "cell phone." This is in American English.